# Artifacts on right edge of screen

Tags: graphics, radeon, display-resolution, 17.04, amd-graphics

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04 and there are is a weird phenomenon occurring on the right side of my screen (Dell P2715Q driven with Sapphire Radeon 6950) when running at 3840x2160. If I put the resolution at 2560x1440 it looks normal, but I'd prefer to be running at the full resolution. The glitches appear to shimmer and respond to movement. A screen shot of the screen looks normal, but a picture taken with my camera shows the problem.

[image: Picture]

I'm using the open-source drivers and I've run

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

The monitor works fine with Windows 7 and 10 (same hardware) as well as MacOS (2013 Mackbook Pro).

Comment: I recommend installing an AMD proprietary video driver.

Comment: @Dante The proprietary video driver is no longer supported in 17.04

Comment: @wklock did you manage to resolve this? I'm having the same issue :/

Comment: @rvalue I did not. I used a different graphics card (GTX 1050), and it works fine now. Really not sure what happened here.